# Django and GeoDjango database backend

Tags: mysql, django, spatial, geodjango

I am using a Django app with MySQL database backend and I want to implement GeoDjango I have  to change backend to:

```
django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql
```

I don't know if that is simple as it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It's that simple but you will have some [spatial limitations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#mysql-spatial-limitations)